# How to set up volume of solid of revolutions about the y-axis

Tags: definite-integrals, volume, solid-of-revolution

Sorry for posting an obvious homework question on here, but Ive been stuck on setting this integral up for quiet some time now.
The problem is:

Consider the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the y-axis.
y = ln x, y = 1, y=3, x = 0

I tried

$$\int_0^{20.0086}\pi ({ln(x)})^2dx$$

I used 20.0086 because ln(20.0086) = 3, but this doesnt seem correct.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of integrating over $dy$ as opposed to $dx$?

Comment: not really @TiwaAina

Comment: Have you sketched the region whose volume you're integrating? You're not integrating the area under $\ln(x)$.

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain an integral over $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
the inverse function of $ y=\ln x$ is $x=e^y$.

So the radius of a circle centered on the $y$ axis and limited by the curve $y=\ln x$ is $r=e^y$ and the volume of a cylinder of infinitesimal height $dy$ is $\pi r^2 dy=\pi (e^y)^2 dy$

Comment: Thank you I didnt know you had to find the inverse of f(x) to  rotate it

Answer (score 0):

This is made simpler if you integrate over $y$. To integrate over $y$, we use the same process we'd use for integrating over $dx$ but with switched variables.

Consider what we'd do if we wanted the volume of $f(x)$ around the x-axis with points $x=2$ and $x=5$. We'd compute $$\pi \int_2^5 (f(x))^2 dx$$ Why? Because our bounds perpendicular to the axis are at $x=2$ and $x=5$ (and 5 is the upper bound because $5 > 2$), and we're calculating using a function "parallel" to our **x**-axis, so we use a function of $x$.

So if we integrate over $y$, we need bounds perpendicular to our **y**-axis (here we will have $y=1$ and $y=3$), and the function "parallel" to the y-axis is the same function given to us in the problem, but we need to turn it into a function of $y$.

So we'd have

$y_{\text{min}} = 1$

$y_{\text{max}} = 3$

$y(x) = \log x \rightarrow x(y) = e^y$.

Then we integrate

$ \pi \int_1^3 (x(y))^2 dy = $
$$\pi \int_1^3 e^{2y} dy = \frac 12 e^2 (e^4-1) \approx 622.098$$

Comment: Thank you I didnt know you had to find the inverse of f(x) to  rotate it